# Several isolated Laragon / Node environments within the same server

Tags: node.js, development-environment, environment, laragon

Is it possible to install several isolated Laragon or NodeJS environments on the same server? So that one can't leave their environment and has no access to other environments or system/root folders.

Comment: If you haven't already, best to ask on the forums: https://forum.laragon.org